# Binding Visibility of ItemsControl

Tags: c#

I have use the following code snippet for binding Visibility of ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PART_ItemsControl"
        Margin="{Binding ExcelLikeFilterAdvVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource marginConverterForOldExcelLikeFiltering}, ConverterParameter=ItemsControl}"
        ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=Items.Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource itemsSourceCountConverter}}">
```

Due to this code snippet I got the following error in output window.

Error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Items' property not found on 'ToolTipsDemo.StocksViewModel' 'ToolTipsDemo.StocksViewModel' (HashCode=42842654). BindingExpression: Path='Items.Count' DataItem='ToolTipsDemo.StocksViewModel' (HashCode=42842654); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl' (Name='PART_ItemsControl'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility')..`

Comment: That code is totally unreadable, please format it... thanks :)

Comment: Hi Rober, Please check now.

Comment: Well the datacontext of your itemscontrol seems to be of Type StocksViewModel, and that viewmodel has no Items property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=Items.Count,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                     Converter={StaticResource itemsSourceCountConverter}}">
```